# Identifying conflicting cells with duplicate IDs in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

So I have an excel table setup consisting of rows with their own IDs. Each ID should be unique but we have a lot of duplicate IDs that I'm trying to remove. So the first thing I tried to do was identify and remove the duplicates using the *Conditional Formatting* and *Remove Duplicates* tool in Excel but unfortunately I'm still left with several rows that share an ID but haven't been removed. So now I have to go into them and look through them manually. I was wondering if there was a way to have excel highlight the discrepancies between the rows. I've provided an example below.

| ID | number | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123abc | 3 | Three |
| 123abc | 4 | Three |
| 456def | 5 | Five |

In this sort of table the discrepancies are 3 and 4 since they belong to the same ID but differ in value so I would want Excel to highlight them. Is this possible in Excel? Thank you.

Comment: You can use COUNTIFS and conditional formatting (note, may bog down the program depending on the amount of data).

Comment: Unfortunately it is quite large with about 3000 rows and 30 columns. I did use conditional formatting to identify the duplicate IDs but that still means I'll have to manually look through them. I was wondering if there was something I could do in VBA but I wasn't sure on how.

Answer (score 0):

if you want just highlight duplicate and unique cell use `Conditional formating`. there is a rule of duplicate filter.

Comment: So I've already done that to identify the duplicate IDs. However the problem is that I want to search through the rows of the duplicate IDs to find discrepancies in the rows.

Comment: do you want to delete it

Comment: Eventually I do want to delete the incorrect rows. For now though, after identifying the duplicate IDs I want to look through the rows to find which ones are wrong. To make it easier for me I thought it would be easier if I could get Excel to highlight the differences between the rows.

Answer (score 0):

In the Number column, use a Conditional Format formula rule like:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$3000,A2)>=2
```

Assuming the ID is in column A, and you may need to change the 3000.
Sorting by the ID column would also be useful.